# How the intern method works when used without assiging it to any reference in java?

Tags: java, string

```
public class abc {

      public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String s1 = new String("abc");          // line 1
        String s2 = s1.concat("abc");           // line 2
        System.out.println(s2 == s2.intern()); // line 3

    } 
}
```

from line 1, s1 stores abc in heap , another abc in scp

from line 2, s2 stores abcabc in heap

then how the line 3, **s2** in heap == **s2.intern()** in scp , prints **true** ?

Comment: `then how the line 3, s2 in heap == s2.intern() in scp , prints true ?` Because `s2.intern()` returns the original string.

Comment: What do you think `intern()` does when the string doesn't exist in the string pool? And what does it return in that case?

Comment: "*from line 2, s2 stores `abcabc` in heap*" what makes you think so?

Comment: @Pschemo since s1.concat("abc") is a runtime operation, it will create an object in heap memory

Comment: "...it will create an object in heap memory" true, but String pool doesn't take *all* heap memory. Being in heap doesn't automatically mean being in String pool. Otherwise all string objects would end up in pool and we wouldn't be able to garbage-collect them causing our applications to at some point run out of memory.

Comment: @tkausi But at line 2,  s2 refer to object abcabc in heap, and at this point abcabc is not in scp, then s2.intern() should create abcabc in scp and return it, so they are two different objects

Comment: NO, it does not create new string. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) of `intern`: *"...if the pool already contains a string equal to this ... **Otherwise**, **this** String object is added to the pool and **a reference to this** String object is returned."* - so they are the same instance

Comment: @user15244370 But if pool doesn't contain "abcabc" already (in line 2 you can check s2 == "abcabc" will return false, thus s2 is in heap not in pool), so intern will have to create "abcabc" in pool when s2.intern() gets called so s2 and s2.intern() should not be same object

Comment: no, `intern` will not have to create "abcabc" - it is already created and `intern` gets that reference (as `this`) and just adds the reference to the pool as described in the documentation *"this String object is added to the pool"* ("this Object" is used to indicate the instance used to call the method in all the documentation) and the same reference is returned (*"reference to this String object is returned"*).

Comment: so you mean it transfers object from heap to pool instead of creating copy of heap string object in string constant pool when not there. if so then the rule is changed as this program prints false in java 1.6